# npm config get python path differs from executable path, Symbols changed

Tags: python, node.js, npm, path

```
gyp ERR! find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "C:\Users\Kolmipyöräinen pyörä\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python - executable path is "C:\Users\Kolmipy�r�inen py�r�\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Kolmipy�r�inen py�r�\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe" could not be run
```

When trying to `npm install openvpn-bin`, it gets the python path but it changes `Kolmipyöräinen pyörä` to `Kolmipy�r�inen py�r�` and it cannot execute.

Comment: Are you running that `npm` command straight from the command line or from a batch file? Because if it is in a script file, the issue is likely that the script file has been saved using the wrong encoding.

Comment: encoding such as utf-8 utf-16. latin-1etc.

Comment: I tried running from cmd and form vsc, both administration mode and normal @grismar.
can i use utf-8 as --encoding:"utf-8" style or?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change the name of the path to english.Maybe it doesn't recognize "Kolmipyöräinen pyörä".

Comment: that's most likely the issue but you can imagine this ain't only place where it's happening so way to implement encoding options on npm install would be gr8

Comment: Hey - this is a nice first try for an answer; sadly, it doesn't address the issue with a definitive solution, just suggests a possible workaround. A good answer should address the issue presented (not the symptom), and be known to work by you. I hope you continue to grow and contribute with the community.